# How to notify UI thread while worker thread is running without using winapi methods C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

in my program I am running a thread that gets some values from a device and then these values need to be displayed on the UI. To realize this I am using an std::thread in order to have a cross platform program. Now the problem is when the thread is running (it could take up to 3 minutes before finishing) and I want to notify the UI thread (to update UI elements) in order to display the values  that are already available. I know that this could be achieved with `PostMessage(...)` but it would require using winapi. So is there a way to achieve this without using winapi ? Here is a simplification of the code that represents what I would like to do.

```
 #include <thread>

 MyClass {
 public:
    // Some initializations
    std::thread t;
    void LoadingParams();
 }

 void MyClass::Init() {
     // Some initializations...
     t = std::thread(&MyClass::LoadingParams, this);
     // ...
 }

 void MyClass::LoadingParams() {
      for(int i=0; i < NB_VALUES; i++) {
          int value = ReadValue();
          // TODO: Send notification to main thread to display the value
          // Alternative to PostMessage
      }
 }
```

So the idea would be to replace the TODO with the notification function.

Comment: An [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) member variable? A [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)? A mix of both?

Comment: You could `notify` a `condition_variable` that the value is ready to be displayed.

Comment: What does your main thread look like? If you have a main render loop, you could simply poll for updated values. If your application is event driven, then you should be able to dispatch an appropriate event from your worker thread. However we can't tell you the specifics, if we don't know what you are using.

Comment: and ui you also create without using windows api ? you at all not using winapi and some windows specific code ?

Comment: @NathanOliver- and what give notify a condition_variable ? ui thread not wait for this variable

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - what sense in atomic here at all and how this can help notify another thread ?

Comment: @RbMm No at the moment the UI runs with windows api but long term project would be to create a cross platform program. For the moment I am translating some little parts to avoid being windows dependent.

Comment: @Rekopx - i very strong doubt that possible send notification to thread without os specific code and knowledge about - what this concrete thread do

Comment: Use the atomic object to contain the value you want to pass from one thread to another. Then you can use polling of that. Or use a condition variable to notify one thread that the value have been updated.